# Java stream как задать условие?

Tags: java, java-stream

Есть лист Integer, я хочу сделать из него строку с помощью stream, но с условием, что если число больше 10 то добавлять к строке "> 10, ", а если меньше, то "< 10, ". Написал код для случая, если число больше 10:

```
String str  = list.stream().filter(i -> i > 10).map(i -> i.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining("> 10, "));
```

Не могу понять как добавить второе условие для "< 10, " в stream. И второй вопрос, почему joining("> 10, ") не срабатывает для последнего элемента. Буду благодарен, если поможете разобраться

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list.stream()
    .map(i -> i < 10 ? i + " < 10" : i + " > 10")
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Comment: Ах, точно. Спасибо большое!

Comment: если можно, еще один вопрос: я правильно понимаю, что для Collectors.joining никак нельзя использовать тернарную операцию, чтобы определить какой suffix использовать, в зависимости от последнего элемента?

Comment: Если нельзя, то буду искать другой способ

Comment: Нельзя. Только если писать свой коллектор.

Comment: Что если i == 10?

Comment: @Sergey добавить вложенный тернарный оператрр или развернуть лямбду в полноценный условный блок.